# Flash AS3: The supplied DisplayObject must be a child of the caller error

Tags: flash, actionscript-3

I am creating some action script to simulate 3 button states and load in movie clips accordingly.

I'm getting this error

```
ArgumentError: Error #2025: The supplied DisplayObject must be a child of the caller.
    at flash.display::DisplayObjectContainer/removeChild()
    at Untitled_fla::MainTimeline/sack_btnMouseOut()
```

When trying to do this

```
//get the objects
var addSackStill:sack_still = new sack_still();
var addSackHover:sack_hover = new sack_hover();
var addSackClick:sack_click = new sack_click();

//add the still object to the stage
addChild(addSackStill);
var SACK_X = 570.55;
var SACK_Y = 603.95;
addSackStill.x = SACK_X;
addSackStill.y = SACK_Y;
addSackHover.x = SACK_X;
addSackHover.y = SACK_Y;
addSackClick.x = SACK_X;
addSackClick.y = SACK_Y;

//create the event listeners
addSackStill.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_OVER, sack_btnMouseOver);
addSackHover.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_OUT, sack_btnMouseOut);
addSackHover.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, sack_btnClick);


//here are the functions for mouse over, mouse off, and click
function sack_btnMouseOver(event:MouseEvent):void {
    trace("mouse over");
    removeChild(addSackStill); //remove the movie clip
    addChild(addSackHover); //add sackclick to the stage
}

function sack_btnMouseOut(event:MouseEvent):void {
    trace("mouse out");
    removeChild(addSackHover); //remove the movie clip
    addChild(addSackStill); //add sackclick to the stage
}

function sack_btnClick(event:MouseEvent):void {
    trace("Click");
    removeChild(addSackHover); //remove the movie clip
    addChild(addSackStill); //add sackclick to the stage
}
```

Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: I normally get this error if I'm calling removeChild from the object I'm trying to remove.. Try wrapping removeChild in if(thing.parent) thing.parent.removeChild(thing);

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm assuming they're not added when you're trying to remove them.  Make sure the parents exist before you remove them.  Also, you can try parent.removeChild, rather than that object's remove:

```
//here are the functions for mouse over, mouse off, and click
function sack_btnMouseOver(event:MouseEvent):void {
    trace("mouse over");
    if (addSackStill.parent) { addSackStill.parent.removeChild(addSackStill); } //remove the movie clip
    addChild(addSackHover); //add sackclick to the stage
}

function sack_btnMouseOut(event:MouseEvent):void {
    trace("mouse out");
    if (addSackHover.parent) { addSackHover.parent.removeChild(addSackHover); } //remove the movie clip
    addChild(addSackStill); //add sackclick to the stage
}

function sack_btnClick(event:MouseEvent):void {
    trace("Click");
    if (addSackHover.parent) { addSackHover.parent.removeChild(addSackHover); } //remove the movie clip
    addChild(addSackStill); //add sackclick to the stage
}
```

Comment: I'm thinking if this were that case that a null object reference error would be thrown instead?

Comment: This is for both possibilities -- both null parent and not parent of removed child ....